# C++Builder: pass command line argument to MainForm from WinMain

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

Borland C++ Builder 6

```
WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
        try
        {
                 AnsiString s = ParamStr(0); // I want to pass this argument
                 Application->Initialize();
                 Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);  // Can't pass here?
                 Application->Run();  // Can't pass here either???
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
```

How do I pass a command line argument/parameter to Form1?

CreateForm doesn't allow overloaded constructors.

Comment: Why not call `ParamStr` from your form?

Comment: Agreed, what Eelke said is the simplest solution. Just have the `TForm1` constructor call `ParamStr()` directly. And FYI, `ParamStr(0)` is the same value as `Application->ExeName`, so you could just use that instead

Answer (score 2):

Creating forms with `CreateForm` does not allow to pass additional arguments directly in *Borland C++ Builder 6*.

You can solve this by creating an additional method to set the arguments:

Unit1.h

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    //...

public:
    void SetCommandLineArguments(const AnsiString& arguments);
    //...
};
```

your form then can be initialized like:

Project1.cpp

```
#include "Unit1.h"
...
AnsiString s = ParamStr(0); // Get the command line argument
Application->Initialize();
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
Form1->SetCommandLineArguments(s);
Application->Run();
```

Comment: "'SetCommandLineArguments' is not a member of 'TForm1', because the type is not yet defined"

I have already tried what you suggested before, it didn't work, this way anyway.  Clearly it's not that simple.

Comment: Fore sure its not a member of ```TForm1``` by default, which is why you have to add it by your own as shown in my answer. I also propose to start with getting familar with the basics of C++ (like creating classes, ...) before working with them.

Comment: "*Creating forms with CreateForm does not allow to pass additional arguments directly in **Borland C++ Builder 6***" - or ANY version of C++Builder (or Delphi), for that matter. This is not a limitation of just BCB6 alone.

Comment: In any case, even if you add a custom method to the `TForm1` class, you have to actually `#include` the Form's header file into the `WinMain` source file in order for the compiler to see it. That header is NOT `#include`'d by default, which is why you are getting the "type is not yet defined" error, as the default code merely uses a forward declaration to satisfy the `__classid` and an `extern` reference to access the `Form1` variable.